# Minimum number of words to define any other

Tags: graphs, minimum-cuts

I'm interested in finding the minimum number of words needed to define some fraction (perhaps 95%) of the words occurring in an English dictionary (while ignoring the challenges of disambiguating conjugations & contractions, questions about what is and is not a word, etc).

My approach to this problem was to program a vertex cover solution after taking a historical Websters dictionary available online, as the following diagram shows (the definitions of the words "*area*", "*extent*", "*big*" and "*size*"):

[image: words]

However, the problem differs from vertex cover in one important way: a if a new word defined by already defined words like "*extent*" and "*area*", this word would *not* need to be 'colored' (selected) because it can be defined exclusively with reference to other statements. However, a basic vertex cover solution would require that word be covered.

With all this in view,

- Does this problem have a formal name?
- Is this problem exactly solved by taking the existing vertex cover and then progressively eliminating any entries which are already otherwise covered?
- Is there a well-known, performant way to solve this generally?

Comment: Possibly related: [Pareto principle (80/20 rule)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) and [Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law). Statistically, you should be able to define 80% of words using 20% of the corpus (defining words) following the Pareto principle. For your first problem, you could probably separate the set of defining words (the definition) and the defined word. This would create a bipartite graph so you no longer worry about *extent* defining *area*, because you now have *extent* as a defining word and as a defined word.

Comment: I would imagine you could more easily formulate this as a combo of [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and set packing. Given a universe $U$, and a collection of sets $S$, we want to choose a subset $P \subset S$, maximizing $m = |P|$ and minimizing $|p_1 \cup p_2 \cup \dots \cup p_m| \subset U$.